# Taking over Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I wanted to create official Facebook page for my organization, but it already exists as a "passive" page. I mean, there's just something like an article copied from Wikipedia and nothing more. Seems like nobody is managing it.

Nevertheless, it has over 3.000 fans!

Is there any possibility to take over this site, without need to say to all of these people "Hey, we are here now, come and click 'like it' again"?

Answer (score 6):

You can use this form to ask Facebook to reconsider:
http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=page_category_change

(Credit where credit's due - I found that via this [helpful article on Facebook pages](http://www.squidoo.com/facebookpage#module131306441).)